# Iphone User Location without manually running app

Tags: iphone, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I need to read the iPhone users location using google maps, but I don't want the user to have to run my app to do so. It doesn't necessarily need to be tracked constantly, but I might want to check the user location every 10 or 20 minutes.

Ideally this feature could be turned off or on by the user, but the most important part is that I don't want to have to run the app in order for it to check the user location. Is this possible? How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

For an iOS 4 multitasking app, you want to read [this document on Receiving Location Events in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).  The user will need to run your app to start the tracking process.